# javascript setInterval timer issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

the code :

```
function startTimer() {
  var i = 0;
  var TimeInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $("#Time").html(i++);
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(TimeInterval);
  }, 2000);
}
```

my problem is that `$("#Time").html(i++)` is always 0 and not incrementing

Comment: I think the problem is that you're stopping the interval before it has chance to run a 2nd time (1st time *will* show 0, but increment i for next time)

Comment: what do you suggest ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, because all of the above can be done by getting rid of both timers and just putting `$("#Time").html("1")` - obviously I know that's not what you want.

Comment: @Sora try commenting `clearInterval()`.

Comment: no of course that is not what i want . what i want to do is incrementing i to show me second elapsed so when 2 minutes are elapsed i want to do something

Comment: Increments to 1 before stopping in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGNV6/)

Comment: then you should place 120000 instead of 2000 in clearInterval :) because 2000 is 2 seconds, not 2 minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
(function startTimer() {//selef executing function
 var i = 0;
 var TimeInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $("#button").html(i++);
   }, 1000);
   })()//end of function
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <p id='button'></p>
 </body> 
</html>
```

> set time out should be removed from your code then it will work.see the above code.it works

Answer (score 0):

```
function startTimer() {
  var i = 0;
  var TimeInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $("#Time").html(++i);
  }, 1000); // This will run every 1000ms == 1s
  setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(TimeInterval);
  }, 2000); // This is 2000 ms == 2s. 120000ms is 2min
}
```

I've only changed `i++` to `++i` - but the difference is probably what you want.

With `i++`, `i` is evaluated first, then incremented - with `++i`, `i` is first incremented, then evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function startTimer() {
  var i = 0;
  var TimeInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $("#Time").html(i++);
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(TimeInterval);
  }, 120000);
}
```

this code increments the html each second, until 2 minutes are passed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easiest with just one timeout that reschedules itself:

```
function countForTwoMins() {
    var count = 1,
        timer = function () {
            $("#Time").html(count++);
        };
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        timer();
        if (count < 120) {
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

countForTwoMins();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ybyu5/

Of course, if you care about arguments.callee being deprecated:

```
function countForTwoMins() {
    var count = 1,

    function callback () {
        $("#Time").html(count++);
        if (count < 120) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000);
        }
    }        
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}
```